# Codeigniter form validation errors stuck in a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm following along with a tut the source files can be found here: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Simple-CI-Authentication

Now when I try and login it keeps looping back saying I have errors where as in the tutorial video his comes back as ok and no errors shown.

```
I get The Email Address field is required.The Password field is required.
```

Even though I have entered input for both fields which is valid here is my code:

application/controllers/admin.php

```
<?php if(! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->model('Admin_model');
            $this->Admin_model->verify_user('test@admin.com', 'test');
            // then validation passed. get from the db.
        }

        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

application/views/login_view.php

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<?php echo form_open('admin'); ?>
<p>
    <?php 
        echo form_label('Email Address: ', 'email_address');
        echo form_input('Email Address', '', 'id="email_address"');
    ?>
</p>
<p>
    <?php 
        echo form_label('Password: ', 'password');
        echo form_password('Password', '', 'id="password"');
    ?>
</p>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Login'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<div class="errors"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the form inputs in the view to:

`form_input('email_address', '', 'id="email_address"');`

`form_password('password', '', 'id="password"');`

Their name must match the name you entered in the rules in the controller.